# Digital Photo Professional alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management, photography, photo-editing

I'm looking for alternative software to develop raw files (cr2) on Ubuntu?

I know that I can use wine to run DPP, but I wonder if there is another option worth trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darktable. This is pretty much the open source counterpart to Adobe's Lightroom. It's pretty good, I've used it for some years now. It's available through the usual Ubuntu repositories.